# NSURLConnection does trigger didReceiveData, but the returned data is zero

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsmutabledata

**Additional question:**
Total received data length is now 89973. But converting it into a string using the code below returns a (null) string. **Solved it:** Changed the encoding to NSASCIIStringEncoding and now it works.

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Received string: %@", responseString);
```

**Solved question:**
I am trying to log into a website and get the returned data.
Everything is working fine and the redirects work like they should.

Also didReceiveData is getting called multiple times, but the strange thing is: The data length is zero. Even if I NSLog the data length from within didReceiveData.

Below are both the .m and .h file and the resulting NSLog information.

I am pretty new to Objective-C and I am trying to fix this for hours now, but I can't seem to find the cause.

I hope someone can have a look for me.

This is the .m file

```
#import "SiteConnection.h"

@implementation SiteConnection

@synthesize username;
@synthesize password;

// Other
- (void) printInstanceVars {

}

- (void) getInformation {
    // Enable Network Indicator
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    // Set the request URL
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com"];

    // Create the request using the URL defined above
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Change User-Agent to a Browser
    [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    // Change method to POST
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Create POST string
    NSString *requestData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=value"];

    // Append POST string to the request
    [request setHTTPBody: [requestData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Initialize the connection
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    // Start the connection
    [connection start];
}

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
         willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
        redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

    // http statuscodes between 300 & 400 is a redirect ...
    if (response && statusCode >= 300 && statusCode < 400) {
        NSLog(@"Redirecting to : %@ (%u)", [request URL], statusCode);
    }

    return request;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [receivedData setLength:0];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSLog(@"Response: %u (%@)", [httpResponse statusCode], [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:[httpResponse statusCode]]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"Receiving data... Length: %d", [receivedData length]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // Hide Network Indicator
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    // Display data length
    NSLog(@"Total received data: %d", [receivedData length]);

    // Convert data into string and display it
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Received string: %@", responseString);
    //NSLog(@"Cookies: %@", [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] description]);
}
```

This is the .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class StatusViewController;

@interface SiteConnection : NSObject {
    NSString *username;
    NSString *password;
    NSURL *url;
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
}

@property NSString *username;
@property NSString *password;

// Other
- (void) printInstanceVars;
- (void) getInformation;

@end
```

This is the resulting NSLog:

```
2012-07-02 15:41:12.578 Vodafone[25051:11303] Response: 200 (no error)
2012-07-02 15:41:12.578 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.580 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.580 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.582 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.583 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.585 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.586 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.587 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.590 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.590 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.591 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.592 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.596 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.601 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.605 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.608 Vodafone[25051:11303] Receiving data... Length: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.608 Vodafone[25051:11303] Total received data: 0
2012-07-02 15:41:12.608 Vodafone[25051:11303] Received string:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if (!receivedData)
    {
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    }

    [receivedData appendData:data];

    NSLog(@"Receiving data... Length: %d", [receivedData length]);
}
```

Comment: why "else" appendData ... ? you just loose the 1st frame.
just if and append in all Case, not if/else

Comment: How stupid of me... Reading your answer made me think: Ah yes, of course.

Thanks a lot! Now on to my next problem.

Comment: luxsyher do u know receivedData is mutabledata

Comment: Actually luxsypher is right if you ask me. Your code only creates an empty data object when the first data is received. That way you trow away the first received data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've forget :

```
NSMutableData *receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you never initialize `receivedData`. So you append your received data to a nil pointer which obviously has no effect ;-)
Try something like `receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];` before you use it.